# How can I get more information about code errors in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

Very often I get errors in PyCharm with no explanations, I also don't know which line the error comes from.

I just get a message like this in the console:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

Is it possible to let it show more information about the error and possibly the line in the code and file?

I Use python and pyqt5

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a nice solution to this problem,
In PyCharm, go in Run menu --> Edit Configurations and there enable: "emulate terminal in output console" 
This will show informations about the errors.